# org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Dismissed user prompt dialog Test runs on console but not in Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-pipeline

I run my test automation with selenium webDriver. It runs perfectly fine in intellij, on my computers cmd and also on the servers cmd (on which Jenkins is running via bat script). However it throws a throws this exception when running my bat file with Jenkins.

This is my error log (I changed some names for security reasons):

```
Feb 13, 2019 1:25:45 PM org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions findElement
WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.cssSelector: a[class="icon-info"])
org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Dismissed user prompt dialog: https://myAuthentification.com is requesting your username and password.: 
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z'
System info: host: 'HOSTSRV', ip: '129.103.116.133', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_141'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 65.0, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.23.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 21192, moz:profile: C:\Windows\Temp\rust_mozpro..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 6.3, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: f3bbe8e0-771b-484e-82c4-ab165de1cb23
```

I already updated Jenkins and all plugins, updated firefox and tried if switchTo().alert.accept() works in different locations .

This is what my method looks like right now:

```
protected void checkForEntitlementAutoIt(WebDriver driver) {

    // waits for alert to be present, if not throws exception
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Settings.waitAlert);
    Alert alert;
    try {
        try {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
            driver.switchTo().alert();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.message(driver, "Alert is present.");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.message(driver, "Alert not present.");
        throw e;

    }

    /* searches for login data
     *    -> if script present, use script
     *    -> if not use data in object "login"
     */
    try {
        if(script != null && new File(script).exists()) {
            Log.message(driver, "Executing script.exe ...");
            Process runExe = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(script);
            runExe.waitFor();
        } else {
            AutoItScript script = new AutoItScript(login.getEmail(), login.getPW());
            script.create();
            script.run();
            script.delete();
        }
        //wait for alert again to check if success
        try {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
            driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch(org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException E) {
        Log.message(driver, "No alert: Authentication succeeded.");
    } catch(org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException E) {
        Log.message(driver, "Timeout: Authentication succeeded.");
    } catch(InterruptedException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.message(driver, "Err: Something went wrong. Exiting...");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

it is supposed to switch to the alert window , then execute the login script and then accept the alert

Comment: why dont you add your URL dto trusted websites in chrome or firefox or whatver broswer you are using so you dont have to go through entering your credetials in the popup alert. at least that what i did in my case. and it solved my problem

Comment: Did you run this on your server using the same user account that jenkins is using?

Comment: @mbn217 I have to switch between two different user accounts in my automation therefore saving my credentials would not help me. But it's a reasonable idea, thank you :)

Comment: @JensDibbern yes I've checked it, Jenkins uses the same user acccount as my server, stil doesn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

So I finally found a solution with is almost too simple, I don't know why I didn't do this earlier (probably because I was so focused on why the alert is not there).

I tried to find another way to enter my credentials into the alert (before I used to execute an extra script with username and password in it).

Now I'm just getting my username an password from the script and use the "sendKeys" argument to put them into the alert. It worked.

Before

```
try {
            Process execScript = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("autoit/autoit.exe " + this.path + this.file);
            execScript.waitFor();
            Log.message("Executed script " + this.file + ".");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
```

After

```
try {
            driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys(this.user+Keys.TAB+this.pw);
            Log.message("send keys");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone end up here like me, for behat/mink:

```
/**
 * Click a button by it's id or name and confirm the dialog
 *
 * @When I click the object :idOrName and confirm
 */
public function iClickAndConfirm($idOrName)
{
    $this->getSession()->getDriver()->executeScript('window.confirm = function () { return true; };');
    $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('named', ['id_or_name', $idOrName])->click();
}
```